# javascript: why need to delete the 0 index of an array

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

in underscore source code, after applying shift or splice on an array and in case the length of the array is zero :

```
 if ((name == 'shift' || name == 'splice') && obj.length === 0) delete obj[0];
```

any idea why still need to do this : `delete obj[0]`

Comment: I didn't do a closer look at the source, so it is just a comment. But as this code is part of a _wrapper_ and not a real array, this might be a necessary fix.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Searching around in the Issue tracker shows that my assumption was right, it is just a fix for an IE bug.

[IE bugs with splice() and shift()](https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/issues/397):

> **jdalton commented on 6 Dec 2011**
>   IE bugs with splice() and shift(), failing to remove the 0 indexed value, when using an array-like-object with _(...).
>   IE compatibility mode and IE < 9 have buggy Array shift() and splice() functions that fail to remove the last element, object[0], of array-like-objects even though the length property is set to 0.